# Fake flashlight volume with smoke: how to make noise texture coordinates not to follow camera

Tags: volumetrics, texture-coordinates

I'am trying to fake effect of volume light beaming through smokey fog using emission shader on torus with noise texture plugged into volume output. I get the effect, but when I move camera around noise on parented torus keeps following which looks fake. However when I rotate or move torus itself noise doesn't move along and stays in one place giving the desired impression of foggy, thick air. Any idea how to fix that? Video example bolow:

[Video example](https://youtu.be/KatdypWBlrk)

[Blend](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15agYzXx5tuVYoxxNfzZMSFEfCiSCOGAk)

Comment: Can't you just plug object into noise instead of camera into noise?

Comment: It doesn't work. Try yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would like to keep the noise to be bound to the world coordinates. This will let you move the camera freely without effecting the noise coordinates. The Position in the Geometry will give you this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set texture coordinates between your geometry node and the noise node. You´ll get it to move like you want.

Also try switching the output geometry node from camera to WINDOW.

Thank you for your consideration in voting me as answer.

BFTC_Schiller

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Pluging noise into geometry - position fixed the issue.

Comment: Fantastic. Vote me up and also select this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I wish I could, but Jackdaw gave me clearer answer which solved the issue. Also Im too new to vote, not enough reputation, sorry. Thanks for good intentions tho!